# Opsworks unable to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-opsworks

I've currently got an opsworks stack using Chef 12 but I seem unable to deploy to it, even with a publicly available git repo that Amazon provide by themselves.

The deploy says it completed successfully but the app code does not exist on the server. The only error I see in the logs (even though it's not labelled as an error) is a 404 page not found which I can only assume is when it tries to grab the repo.

According to this question [Opsworks deploy to custom layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35345664/opsworks-deploy-to-custom-layer) do I need to use https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.4/deploy as well in my custom cookbook for the deploy to work? Is it just a case of referencing say the php deploy recipe as part of my deploy phase in my layer?

Thanks

Comment: can you describe your steps and paste the relevant parts of the logs?

Comment: I've deleted the stack I'm afraid (as I'm just playing around with opsworks at the moment) but the steps are, I have a custom cookbook which installs my dependencies, this works fine. I then set-up an app using Amazons php simple app https://github.com/awslabs/opsworks-demo-php-simple-app

The deploy script says it runs fine, and the only thing I see in the logs is a reference to a 404. I have a feeling it's because my custom recipe needs to use a custom deploy script as well